# Using static framework, like Realm, with React-Native installed through Cocoapods

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, realm, react-native-navigation

I have a react-native project that has two requirements. It needs to work with Airbnb's [native-navigation library](http://airbnb.io/native-navigation/docs/installation.html) and it requires a [Realm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/realm) database. I'm having a time getting the two libraries to work togeather. Because Native-navigation uses Swift files, it requires that react-native, and other native libraries are installed through cocoapods.

Realm, is not a cocoapod friendly library so I have been following this basic setup where I start with airbnb's boilerplate `ReactNativeStarter`. At this point the project builds and runs but when I introduce Realm I get an **error when I build the project that it can't find React header files**.

Here are my steps:

**1)** Install realm through `npm install --save realm`

**2)** Dig into `/node_modules/realm/react-native/ios/` and drag `RealmReact.xcodeproj` into the boilerplate generated `ReactNativeStarter` project within the `ReactNativeStarter.xcworkspace` file

[image]

**3)** I then add to the following to the header search path for Realm React `$(SRCROOT)/../../../../ios/Pods/Headers/Public`

[image]

*I think it's worth noting that the /Pods/Headers folder contains nothing. Is this [possibly an issue with cocoapods not generating the header files](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4605) for React properly?*

**4)** I add `libRealmReact.a` static library under 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries'

[image]

**5)** Finally, I add `$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/realm/src`to the header search paths for ReactNativeStarter project.[image]

**Problem** - At this point building the project still results in the following xcode build error:

/Users/some.guy/ReactNative/SaveAs/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTBridge.h:12:9: 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found

Comment: Any reason you're not linking the library with `react-native link`? I recently had problems with Realm when linking it manually.

Comment: @scooper. Yes I tried linking with react-native link also. Same results.

Comment: I am experiencing similar issues with a different library. Were you ever able to resolve this?